# API to track crash occuring in Dynamic TVos framework

Tags: tvos

I'm creating the tvOS framework and want to integrate some third party API to track Crashes occurring in source code of framework.

Is there any API which track the crashes occuring in Dynamic tvOS Framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Tried Crashlytics????

Comment: Its not working for dynamic framework

Comment: okay its a limitation!!